# Using jq to combine json files, getting file list length too long error

Tags: json, linux, jq

Using `jq` to concat json files in a directory.

The directory contains a few hundred thousand files.

`jq -s '.' *.json > output.json`

returns an error that the file list is too long. Is there a way to write this that uses a method that will take in more files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `jq -s . *.json > output.json` produces "argument list too long"; you could [fix it using `zargs` in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128559/1321):

```
$ zargs *.json -- cat | jq -s . > output.json
```

That you could emulate using `find` as shown in [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33885014/4279):

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -name \*.json -exec cat {} + | jq -s . > output.json
```

[*"Data in jq is represented as streams of JSON values ... This is a `cat`-friendly format - you can just join two JSON streams together and get a valid JSON stream."*](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/):

```
$ echo '{"a":1}{"b":2}' | jq -s .
[
  {
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

[EDITED to use find]

One obvious thing to consider would be to process one file at a time, and then "slurp" them:

```
$ while IFS= read -r f ; cat "$f" ; done <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.json") | jq -s .
```

This however would presumably require a lot of memory. Thus the following may be closer to what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash
# "slurp" a bunch of files
# Requires a version of jq with 'inputs'.
echo "["
while read f
do
  jq -nr 'inputs | (., ",")' $f
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.json") | sed '$d'
echo "]"
```

Comment: It's not obvious to me that I can do that, because AFAIK what I was doing was taking a bunch of individual json objects `{...}` and putting them into a well formed array of objects `[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]`. does that still happen with what you're proposing?

Comment: [Don't use `ls` like this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You can simply use a `for` loop instead: `for f in *.json; do cat "$f"; done | jq -s '.'`. (In fact, `ls *.json` will fail for the same reason the original does: too many command line arguments resulting from the pathname expansion.)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `find` like this, either, although it would only really pose a problem if one of the JSON files had a newline in its name. Some other file names could be problematic, but can be handled using `IFS= read -r f` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the length of a command line is limited, and `*.json` produces too many argument for one command line. One workaround is to expand the pattern in a `for` loop, which does not have the same limits as a command line, because `bash` can iterate over the result internally rather than having to construct an argument list for an external command:

```
for f in *.json; do
    cat "$f"
done | jq -s '.' > output.json
```

This is rather inefficient, though, since it requires running `cat` once for each file. A more efficient solution is to use `find` to call `cat` with as many files as possible each time.

```
find . -name '*.json' -exec cat '{}' + | jq -s '.' > output.json
```

(You may be able to simply use

```
find . -name '*.json' -exec jq -s '{}' + > output.json
```

as well; it may depend on what is in the files and how multiple calls to `jq` using the `-s` option compares to a single call.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not replicate the desired behavior of the jq option "-s".   (The "slurp" option creates a JSON array from a *stream* of JSON entities.)

Comment: You could probably fix that by piping the result of that final `find` command to an appropriate invocation of `jq` (`jq '.[] |[.]'`?), but it's probably not worth the effort to get right.